# Claims + Tokens library for c#

Tags: c#, security, token, claims-based-identity

Is there a library for c# that allows me to build an encrypted token containing claims, and then gives me an API to check if a token contains the claims I'm interested in?
Similar to how ".NET Access Control Service" works.
I hope the question is clear. Thanks, Nestor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Geneva Framework